# Performance impact with many instances of a class

Tags: javascript

I have some old code that I would like to refactor and improve, currently the code looks something like this:

```js
function objFunction1(obj){
  //do something
  console.log(obj, 1);
}

function objFunction2(obj){
  //do something else
  console.log(obj, 2)
}

var obj = {test: true};

objFunction1(obj);
objFunction2(obj);
```

I am thinking of makeing it into a class eg:

```js
class item{
  constructor(test){
    this.test = test;
    return this;
  }
  
  function1(){
    console.log(this, 1);
  }
  
  function2(){
    console.log(this, 2);
  }
}

var obj = new item(true);
obj.function1();
obj.function2();
```

How does JavaScript handle this? if I was to have 10,000 instances of `item` does JavaScript duplicate those methods for each instance or does it just store a reference to the class declaration?

what I am basically asking, is my original code more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried profiling each approach?

Comment: classes, most often, won't offer you performance benefits over simple function declarations - you can test this yourself or look at some [benchmarks](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/12063/0/function-vs-class#latest_results_block)

Comment: @justinw I was more wondering if there was any downside to class declaration over simple functions as I do not want to add extra overhead if the only real benefit is clearing up the global scope (at least for this use case). I can see more benefits in the future, eg. new `item` types by extending the `item` class.

Comment: @Phil Code Review won't take stub code. This would be closed immediately, so please don't recommend posting it there.

Comment: @Mast fair enough, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you have `100000` or any number of objects, but `function1` and `function2` will have only single copy in its `prototype`**

Since class syntax is just syntactic sugar over the old function constructor. When you write above class syntax then the methods are declared in the `prototype` of that class and you can verify it as:

```
const obj1 = new item(true);
const obj2 = new item(false);
obj1.function1 === obj2.function1;
```

If `obj1.function1 === obj2.function1` expression returns `true` then that means, there is only one function that is defined in its `prototype`

[You should read docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```js
class item {
  constructor(test) {
    this.test = test;
    return this;
  }

  function1() {
    console.log(this, 1);
  }

  function2() {
    console.log(this, 2);
  }
}

const obj1 = new item(true);
const obj2 = new item(false);
console.log(obj1.function1 === obj2.function1);  // true
```

---

**Note: I've capitalize the first-letter of constructor function that externally specifies that it is a constructor function. It is just a convention used in JS community**

The above class syntax will be equal to the following function constructor syntax as:

```js
function function1() {
  console.log(this, 1);
}

function function2() {
  console.log(this, 2);
}

function Item(test) {
  this.test = test;
}

Item.prototype.function1 = function1;
Item.prototype.function2 = function2;

const obj1 = new Item(true);
const obj2 = new Item(false);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj1.function1 === obj2.function1);
```

Comment: *Since class syntax is just syntactic sugar...* - I think the OP is also trying to figure out if the class methodology will offer performance benefits over function declarations (as mentioned in the last part of the question) - which I would *imagine* a is a clear *no* (not to mention the readability benefits of simple function declarations)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: no.

The functions would not be duplicated; only one definition for each function would be created as the objects' prototype.

JavaScript uses prototype-based inheritance, which means that objects have a prototype that "contain" the methods shared by all the objects from the same prototype:

> JavaScript is often described as a prototype-based language — to
> provide inheritance, objects can have a prototype object, which acts
> as a template object that it inherits methods and properties from.

(source: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes))

If you declare two objects using the same "class" you can see that their instances are different but the methods are the same

```
var objA = new item(true);
var objB = new item(true);

objA === objB // false
objA.function1 === objA.function // true
```

You can access to the prototype of the object by using the somewhat deprecated (but still supported by Chrome) [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property:

```
objA.__proto__ === objB.__proto__ // true
```

So in terms of both memory and execution time, the two options are probably nearly identical.

Comment: There's also `Object.getPrototypeOf()` which isn't deprecated -- you don't have to edit your post; I'm just saying this for you to know.

Comment: You're right, thanks!